# How to replace selected needle in string

Tags: php

I have string: `"[a,b] some text [b,a] and some more"`

I also have value called `$c`, which, if is equal to `1`, I need to show string like that:
`"a some text b and some more"` (selects first part of [x,y] (x))

I try to do that with `str_replace`, but it seems to not work.

Can you please provide a solution?

Comment: I think that's a job for preg_replace instead.

Comment: Could you suggest how to do that?

Comment: What's your use-case for this? Or is it course/homework?

Comment: @JonStirling For my project, I am writing function to show text by person's gender.

Comment: Then have a single placeholder, and replace the placeholder with a string. Don't do this custom variable options in a string thing :P

Comment: @JonStirling Is there no preg_replace solution for this?

Comment: I'm sure there could be one that might include using preg_replace, but I can't think of a way of doing it that isn't evil, unmaintainable and generally over-engineered.

Comment: What are the other possible values of `$c`?

Comment: @Nick Only 1 or 0, 1 show 'a', if 0, shows 'b' instead of [a,b]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `$c` variable to change the substitution string for a call to `preg_replace`, for example:

```
$string = "[a,b] some text [b,a] and some more";
$c = 1;
echo preg_replace('/\[([^,]+),([^]]+)\]/', $c ? '$1' : '$2', $string) . "\n";
$c = 0;
echo preg_replace('/\[([^,]+),([^]]+)\]/', $c ? '$1' : '$2', $string) . "\n";
```

The regex looks for a `[`, followed by some number of non-`,` characters (group 1), a `,`, then some number of non-`]` characters (group 2) and a `]`. The matched text is replaced with either group 1 or group 2 dependent on the value of `$c`.

Output:

```
a some text b and some more 
b some text a and some more
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bXXeO)

Answer (score 0):

I did it for a substrings in one [theard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54073933/10774873), you can use this solution in your case also.