# How can I swap the values of two different characters in a string with PHP? A becomes B, B becomes A

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string in PHP. I want to swap a certain character with the value from another character. If I do it my way, A becoming B will replace A with B but the already existing B values will remain the same. When I try to swap B into A, there are, of course, values that were not originally swapped, because they were already there.

I tried this code.

```
$hex = "long_hex_string_not_included_here";
$hex = str_replace($a,$b,$hex);
//using this later will produced unwanted extra swaps
$hex = str_replace($b,$a,$hex);
```

I am looking for a function to swap these values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php). It's what it was designed for:

```
$string = "abcbca";
echo strtr($string, array('a' => 'b', 'b' => 'a'));
```

Output:

```
bacacb
```

The key functionality that helps here is that when `strtr` is called in the two argument form:

> Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again.

This is what stops the `a` that was replaced by `b` then being replaced by `a` again.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/VMmvT)

Comment: For byte swapping, it's even shorter... `echo strtr($string, 'ab', 'ba');`

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah, OP actually has `$a` and `$b`, I just chose `a` and `b` since I didn't know what was in those variables. The thought was that OP would then substitute `$a` and `$b` back again...

Answer (score 3):

We *could* just try to substitute some third intermediate value for `B`, then replace all `A` to `B`, and then replace the marker back to `A`.  But this always leaves open the possibility that the marker character might already appears somewhere in the string.

A safer approach is to covert the input string into an array of characters, and then walk down the array simply checking each index for `A` or `B`, and swapping accordingly.

```
$input = "AzzzzB";
echo $input ."\n";
$arr = str_split($input);

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    if ($arr[$i] == 'A') {
        $arr[$i] = 'B';
    }
    else if ($arr[$i] == 'B') {
        $arr[$i] = 'A';
    }
}
$output = implode('', $arr);
echo $ouput;

AzzzzB
BzzzzA
```

Note also that this approach is efficient, and only requires walking down the input string once.

Comment: Though this hasn't got the probpem of the intermediate value existsing in the string, this wont work for charlengths >1. And im curious how this performs. My intermediate does have an extra replace, bit it's also string manipulation. I like this answer though, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Temp value (which doesnt occur in your string. Could be anything):

```
$temp = "_";
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
$hex = "abcdabcd";
$hex = str_replace($a,    $temp, $hex); // "_bcd_bcd"
$hex = str_replace($b,    $a,    $hex); // "_acd_acd"
$hex = str_replace($temp, $a,    $hex); // "bacdbacd"

// Or, alternativly a bit shorter:
$temp = "_";
$a = "a";
$b = "b";
$hex = str_replace([$a, $b, $temp], [$temp, $a, $b] $hex);
```

Comment: But of course you will have to make sure that the C value does not already exist in the string or you will get another undesired result

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) the string and use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) test per character. If `a`, return `b` and vice versa. Else return the original value.

```
$hex = "abba test baab";
$hex = array_map(function ($x) {
    return ($x === 'a') ? 'b' : (($x === 'b') ? 'a' : $x);
}, str_split($hex));

echo implode('', $hex);
```

Result

```
baab test abba
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/eCaFP)

Answer (score 0):

My solution works for a substrings. The code is not clear but I want to show you a way of thinking.

```
$html = "dasdfdasdff";
$firstLetter = "d";
$secondLetter = "a";
$firstLetterPositions = array();
$secondLetterPositions = array();

$lastPos = 0;
while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $firstLetter, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $firstLetterPositions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($firstLetter);
}

$lastPos = 0;
while (($lastPos = strpos($html, $secondLetter, $lastPos))!== false) {
    $secondLetterPositions[] = $lastPos;
    $lastPos = $lastPos + strlen($secondLetter);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($firstLetterPositions); $i++) {
    $html = substr_replace($html, $secondLetter, $firstLetterPositions[$i], count($firstLetterPositions[$i]));
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($secondLetterPositions); $i++) {
    $html = substr_replace($html, $firstLetter, $secondLetterPositions[$i], count($secondLetterPositions[$i]));
}
var_dump($html);
```

Comment: Doesnt this fail when you replace a string with another length value? E.g. 'a' with 'bb'? This solution is pretty overkill compared to 3 string replaces and doesnt offer a lot of value.