# preg_replace() catch the first match

Tags: php, regex

I am replacing some code to `del` and `ins` html tag using `PHP`.

For example, my code is:

```
$text = 'This is (foo)((bar))';

$text = preg_replace('/\((.*)\)*/', '<del>$1</del>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\(\((.*)\)\)/', '<ins>$1</ins>', $text);
```

Output I get:

```
This is <del>foo)((bar)</del>
```

Which means, it catches the last closing bracket.

Output I want:

```
This is <del>foo</del><ins>bar</ins>
```

Thwn, how to catch the first closing bracket?

Yes, I can solve it by replacing `ins` tag first like this:

```
$text = 'This is (foo)((bar))';

$text = preg_replace('/\(\((.*)\)\)/', '<ins>$1</ins>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\((.*)\)*/', '<del>$1</del>', $text);
```

But is there any better solution without moving like this?

Answer (score 3):

If your only use of parentheses is for tags, you could just use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```php
$text = 'This is (foo)((bar))';

$text = strtr($text, array('(' => '<del>', ')' => '</del>', '((' => '<ins>', '))' => '</ins>'));
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
This is <del>foo</del><ins>bar</ins>
```

`strtr` works in this situation because it replaces the longer strings in the array first so any `((...))` will be replaced with `ins` tags before the string is parsed for `(...)` to replace with `del` tags.

Otherwise, you will need to check that the opening `(` is not preceded or followed by another `(` when replacing with `del` tags, which you can do with negative lookarounds:

```php
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\()\((?!\()([^)]*)\)/', '<del>$1</del>', $text);
$text = preg_replace('/\(\(([^)]*)\)\)/', '<ins>$1</ins>', $text);
echo $text;
```

Output:

```
This is <del>foo</del><ins>bar</ins>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dfvgQ)

Note that using `[^)]*\)` is more efficient than `.*?\)` due to [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast).

Comment: I didn't expect the `strtr` idea to also work for [`((a))(b)`](https://tio.run/##PYxLCoAgFAD3nuItgvceCB1ArW1Lr2AlFESJuqjTG9hnOcMwYQml6N4OVjTZnxkMIJFjppFRiV@mHHOkShJcjO4iJATTAerZbx1KQH65/QR9xbqnp/iTapiV8NNyQP2qUm4). [Looking it up](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) obviously it replaces longer keys first: *The longest keys will be tried first. Once a substring has been replaced, its new value will not be searched again...* Really useful and maybe worth to be mentioned.

Comment: @bobblebubble good point, I've done so. It's also really useful when you have to swap characters e.g. `a` => `b` and `b` => `a` e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54073460/9473764